# Laravel Auth in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have some problems with authentication on my middleware file.
I'm logging on which page is client last seen, like so:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        Activity::create(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'ip_id' => SecureAgent::getIP(), 'action' => $request->method(), 'page' => $request->path()]);
        

        return $next($request);
    }
```

File in Karnel is added in $middleware;

The problem is that Auth::id() is not working, only NULL. I have logged in with passport, set my token and redirect to profile page, everything is working fine except this middleware.

Comment: use Auth::user()->id

Answer (score 0):

The `Auth::user()` will give you access to current loggined user in system, 
you need to change `'user_id' => Auth::id()` to `'user_id' => Auth::user()->id`